# Помогите с простым выражением

Tags: javascript

Число введенное пользователем должно быть:

1. от 100 до 999
2. число четное
3. не кратное 10
4. кратно 100, не кратно 300
5. 650 и 750 вернет `true`

Вот мой код, что не так?

```
var num, res, message;
num=prompt('enter a num');
num=+num;
res=(num/650==0)&&(num/750==0)&&num>=100&&num<=999&&num%2==0&&num%10!==0&&num%100==0&&num%300!==0;
message='Your number (true-even, false-odd): '+res;
alert(message);
```

Comment: деление на 650 и 750 должно вернуть true?

Comment: у вас взаимоисключающие не кратно 10 и кратно 100. потому как число кратное 100 кратно и 10

Comment: Никак не пойму назначение этой части: (num/650==0)&&(num/750==0). Ведь чтобы при делении числа на 650 получился 0, надо, чтобы число было нулём.

Comment: все дает фолс( незнаю как все сделать правильно((

Answer (score 3):

Коварные правила :)
`999` вообще никогда не вернётся из-за второго пункта, зачем его включать?
Видимо правило о кратности 100 перекрывает правило о запрете кратности 10, иначе в правилах ошибка (всё, что кратно 100, будет точно кратно 10).

---

> от 100 до 999

1. `99` - false
2. `1000` - false

> число четное

3. `102` - true

> не кратное 10

4. `110` - false

> кратно 100, не кратно 300

5. `100` - true
6. `300` - false

> 650 и 750 вернет `true`

7. `650` - true
8. `750` - true

---

```js
let log         = document.querySelector('#result'),
    input       = document.querySelector('#input'),
    printResult = e => (log.style.color = msgType ? 'green' : 'red') && (log.innerHTML = msgType ? 'Passed :)' : 'Not passed!'),
  msgType       = 0;

function checkInput(e){
  let value = this.value.trim();
  msgType = 0;
  
  if(value === ''){
    log.innerHTML = '';
    return;
  }

  if(!/^\d+$/.test(value))
    printResult();

  value = +value;

  msgType = (value === 650 || value === 750) || (
    (value >= 100 && value <= 999) &&
    (value % 2 === 0) && 
    ((value % 100 === 0 && value % 300 !== 0) || (value % 10 !== 0))
  );
  
  printResult();
}

input.addEventListener('input', checkInput);
```

```css
#input:focus{outline: none;}
```

```html
<link href="tests/qunit/qunit-2.0.1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="tests/qunit/qunit-2.0.1.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>От 100 до 999</li>
  <li>Число четное</li>
  <li>Не кратное 10</li>
  <li>Кратно 100, не кратно 300</li>
  <li>650 и 750 вернет true</li>
</ul>

<input type='text' id='input' autofocus />
<br />
<span id='result'></span>
```